# Connecting to the GoPro Wi-Fi network through a router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, gopro, gopro-wifi

I have a GoPro Hero3+ camera, and I want to stream it to my PC. Looking online there are many guides to doing just that, but they all require me to be on the same Wi-Fi network as the GoPro itself.

My PC doesn't have a  Wi-Fi; it's connected to a wireless router (D-Link DSK-6850U). Is there a way to connect my router to the GoPro Wi-Fi network, therefore "extending" my LAN to include the GoPro, so I could connect to it from the PC?

Comment: +1 I've been trying to do a very similar task myself.

Comment: i have same need, would like to connect 10 of these to a wifi network. access each over tcp/ip. in theory it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not that easy. Because this GoPro acts as Wifi-AP. So your Wifi-Router should connect you to the GoPro as Client.

I think one solution could be to setup a raspberry pi with an wifi antenna and connect it to the GoPro. Now connect the raspberry pi into you network via LAN.

Now there are 2 ways to connect to the go pro.

1. Connect via something like vnc to you raspberry pi and open a web browser on the raspberry and open the URL from the gopro
2. Setup a routing between this 2 networks on the raspberry and you client

The second solution is more difficult, but if it is setup you can connect to your gopro via your own network.

Comment: Or 3rd way - Buy a $5 USB WiFi adapter for the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I will just spill out few ideas here, and you see what you can work from that

**1. Additional router**

You could buy an additional router, which you would change to client mode (it would connect to gopro), and connect it to GoPro. Then, that router would be connected to your existing router, thus giving you connection from your computer to the camera.

Bad side of this is obviously buying a new router. On the bright side, router would probably automatically connect when the camera is in range and you would have instant access.

**2. Current router**

If you are not using your current router's wi-fi (highly unlikely, but possible), you could change its mode of operation to client, and work same as no (1)

**3. USB Wi-Fi for your computer**

As already pointed out above, you can buy cheap USB Wi-Fi adapter for the computer.

**4. Removable disk over the LAN**

If I read right, when you connect your GoPro to the computer, you get the removable disk from which you can copy files? If so, then you could find a router (or maybe your current router has an option) to which you could connect GoPro using USB and share its storage with everyone on network.

Downside of this is that GoPro probably cannot work while connected to USB, which means you will probably be unable to record while connected, although I am not sure about that. Also, this is basically the same as connecting GoPro to the computer (i.e. is not wireless).

This all is only my opinion, and I don't know if any of these ideas are applicable to your case.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: I did option #3, but I can't access the files at the normal VPN IP now `10.5.5.9:8080`.  I have a Hero 3+

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do what the author described.

I have linksys switch with DD-WRT installed. I have examined the wireless modes and I guess that one is missing to be created yet, which would allow what you have discribed and what i also tried yesterday (and i'm googling for the sollution).

What i managed to do: create a bridge to mobile phone`s access point (camera or in my case mobile phone access point, to emulate cameras access point) and at the same time keep the internet connection on the switch. So only the packages were able to arrive towars the phone, but the network couldn't see it after all.

So i gues currently it's impossible to do what you described and what i was seeking for also (maybe it will be in future though).

As an extra way to stream: you can get a video card with HDMI INPUT (those are a bit more expensive). This doesn't cover what you are looking for, but adds an extra option to consider.

Answer (score 0):

supply the model name of your router to this website here
https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/
download the firmware that fits your specific model(not newer than or it may brick your device from being to big of a file to fit on memory)
download the software to upload the firmware to your router or login to your router using its ip address findable in windows xp or greater by typing 
[windows key and r] [cmd] [enter]
then
[ipconfig][enter] and copying the value of ip address (the short one not ipv6) such as 192.168.0.1 or 10.0.0.1
then
open your browser and paste your routers ip address(its like a phone number) and push enter

you will be promted for a password which is admin Admin or administrator for a username and iether empty or motorola or the password is printed on your router or available by calling your isp tech support hotline.

once logged in

> you WILL have to reconnect your wifi when you do the below step<
>   nagivate to your routers update or firmware page and upload the firmware file and then wait about 10 minutes while it uploads and reboots.

finally, enable your needed features https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT#Features to relay or lan connect the gopro.

you may need ddwrt MEGA version to get the supported features.